# Linux Sync() equivalent windows API

Tags: linux, windows, memory-management

Linux "sync( ) API will writes any data buffered in memory out to disk. Is there any equivalent call in Windows?

Comment: Why would you expect an exact equivalent of each Linux syscall in Windows. They are very differently designed operating systems! If you need to code for Windows (which I don't know) try to learn it alone with a fresh mind.

Answer (score 3):

The [FlushFileBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is the equivalent API, although it works more similary to the linux `fsync` call in the typical use case in that it takes a file handle as a parameter. For `sync` like behavior you can call `FlushFileBuffers` with a handle to the volume as described in the documentation I've linked to. This requires the appropriate privileges.

Comment: Note that you can open a volume device and call FlushFileBuffers() on the handle to the volume which will flush all open files on that volume. Note though that if you open the volume without the FILE_SHARE_WRITE flag , it will also flush *and* invalidate the file cache.