# How to clear the hard disk cache programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows, disk-io

Is there a method in Windows to clear the whole disk cache? I am doing benchmarks on a disk and try to measure which of my methods has the best performance in C#. The problem is though that the disk caching in Windows prevents me from from getting correct results.

So the question is if there is a method to remove all cached files from the Windows disk cache?

RamMap from SysInternals is able to do it, so there must be a way, but I couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: you can try to run cmd commands to do it

Comment: Have a look at this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593906/linux-sync-equivalent-windows-api) from 2013.

Comment: @AxelKemper: I'm not sure if FlushFileBuffer really remove the cache from the windows memory manager. RamMap example tells me that the file is still mapped. Also FLushFileBuffers is (at least I though) only to force a writethrough, right? My files are open in readonly mode, nothing is written.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7701908/2557128) seems like what you want, though it is probably depending on undocumented operation.

Comment: @NetMage: Thx a lot. I will try this one.